# Streaming audio from microphone in iPhone using Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, audio, xamarin.ios, audioqueueservices

[Recording with AudioQueue and Monotouch static sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002449/recording-with-audioqueue-and-monotouch-static-sound) demonstrates how to get audio via an iPhone's microphone into an AudioQueue using Xamarin.iOS. My question is: how do I keep the microphone continuously recording? I basically want to keep the microphone on for as long as the app is open, and continuously capture the audio stream (note that I do not want to save the stream to file). Inside a long-running while-loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work: https://github.com/sami1971/SimplyMobile/blob/master/iOS/SimplyMobile.Media/Audio/AudioStream.cs

Initialize and use Start() on application start and then call Stop() when application closes (or goes background). Captured buffers are delivered through event handler OnBroadcast.

EDIT: Here is a quick WaveRecorder class. I have not had time to test it so if you find bugs in it, please push back changes or let me know what needs to be changed. https://github.com/sami1971/SimplyMobile/blob/master/Core/SimplyMobile.Media/Audio/WaveRecorder.cs

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly! But now I am struggling to play the stream produced - trying to use the example from Xamarin [Streaming Audio](http://docs.xamarin.com/samples/StreamingAudio/). Am able to successfully stream an MP3, but not the audio from the microphone.

Comment: If you are saving the output to a file then you need to add WAV headers to it first, otherwise it is pure PCM. Writing a wave output isn't very difficult, I might add one to my library if I can find time tonight.

Comment: Nope, not recording first, so it is pure PCM. Thanks for your help!