# Xamarin.Iphone App crashes when running code to enable InputAudioQueue

Tags: xamarin.ios, recording

I'm trying to implement the code on the below link 
[Recording with AudioQueue and Monotouch static sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13002449/recording-with-audioqueue-and-monotouch-static-sound)
to use the microphone to record sounds from the microphone and the app is constantly crashing with the below stack trace:

```
critical: 
Native stacktrace:
2016-10-04 15:41:51.119 JUser[3163:1136833] critical: 0   JUser                           0x000000010012bd68 mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 260
2016-10-04 15:41:51.119 JUser[3163:1136833] critical: 1   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x0000000192cff348 _sigtramp + 52
2016-10-04 15:41:51.119 JUser[3163:1136833] critical: 2   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x0000000192c39480 <redacted> + 100
2016-10-04 15:41:51.120 JUser[3163:1136833] critical: 3   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x0000000192c394c8 system_set_sfi_window + 0
2016-10-04 15:41:51.120 JUser[3163:1136833] critical: 4   TCC                                 0x0000000195e7a560 <redacted> + 0
2016-10-04 15:41:51.120 JUser[3163:1136833] critical: 5   TCC                                 0x0000000195e7a45c <redacted> + 0
2016-10-04 15:41:51.120 JUser[3163:1136833] critical: 6   TCC                                 0x0000000195e7d52c <redacted> + 288
2016-10-04 15:41:51.120 JUser[3163:1136833] critical: 7   libxpc.dylib                        0x0000000192d4401c <redacted> + 80
2016-10-04 15:41:51.120 JUser[3163:1136833] critical: 8   libxpc.dylib                        0x0000000192d43f8c <redacted> + 40
2016-10-04 15:41:51.120 JUser[3163:1136833] critical: 9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000192af91c0 <redacted> + 16
2016-10-04 15:41:51.120 JUser[3163:1136833] critical: 10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000192b07ab4 <redacted> + 732
2016-10-04 15:41:51.120 JUser[3163:1136833] critical: 11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000192b0938c <redacted> + 572
2016-10-04 15:41:51.120 JUser[3163:1136833] critical: 12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000192b090ec <redacted> + 124
2016-10-04 15:41:51.120 JUser[3163:1136833] critical: 13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000192d012c8 _pthread_wqthread + 1288
2016-10-04 15:41:51.121 JUser[3163:1136833] critical: 14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000192d00db4 start_wqthread + 4
2016-10-04 15:41:51.121 JUser[3163:1136833] critical: 
=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

I tried to wrap the code in `try catch` but still experiencing crashes. Any idea what might be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution in case someone else faces the same issue .You will need to add [Privacy -Microphone Usage Description] property to the info.list with a text description so that the app will ask you to allow access to use the microphone .

Comment: Thank you, Ayad.  I encountered same issue with Camera permission.  Unfortunately, the stack trace does not give clear indications - no hint that it's a plist permissions issue.  I have logged my complaint in Xamarin Forums; maybe should have gone to Stackoverflow to log.

Comment: You mean 'Info.plist'